# Your methods for object-oriented coding NodeJS / JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop, ide

I am not a professional programmer, I am working on a project at the moment and I have difficulties, to manage my code. I can barely get to 900 lines of code (not bad) but the problem is that I have a hard time finding myself in all of this, despite all the efforts of the world to heal the legibility, vocabulary and the syntax. I split my big main.js file into 4 smaller file thanks to the modules of NodeJS, but it seems ambiguous compared to the classic import of other language. I use Notepad ++ as an IDE, I have never really worked on a big project (+1000 lines of codes / week).

Would there be standards defined by experts to encode Javascript in a clean way?

Do you have any advice to give me to manage the project?

thanks to all of you

Comment: Notepadd++ is not an IDE, rather an editor. You should try Visual Studio Code, which is a much better one, especially for JS code. Each module should do one thing, and one only.

Comment: Split it into 1 - 3 pages blocks based on functionality. And IDEs like http://atom.io can hide functions bodys etc.

Comment: Thank you for your help indeed it is much more complete than notepad ++

Comment: Sublime Text 3 is your friend